# Javascript: override native DOM method

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to make my website(actually a web app) packaged into single file. I know a easiest way is to replace all path/url inside my code into data-url. But it will make the file hard to read by human. My idea is to use an array to store all data-url and write a function to obtain them by original url(as query string). It can also return the original url if nothing found.
Example:

```
store = new Array();
store.push({"url":"/img/icon.png","data-url":"dataurl:XXXXX"});
store.push({"url":"/img/icon1.png","data-url":"dataurl:XXXXX"});

function getResource(url) {
    var result = url;
    for(var row in store){ 
        if (row.url == url) {
            result = row.data-url;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So to use it, you also need a method to change the attribute in HTML element:

```
function replaceResource(e,attbName) {
    e.target.setAttribute(attbName,getResource(e.target.getAttribute(attbName));
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<img src="/img/icon.png" onload="replaceResource(event,'src');" />
```

But I want to be simpler(since it's not good for human to read also). I want to override the DOM method for each type of HTMLElement(img,script etc.) by something like:

```
HTMLImageElement.prototype.src.callback = function (event) {
    e.target.src = getResource(e.target.src);
}
```

So you don't need to do anything in HTML:

```
<img src="/img/icon.png" />
```

However the code for overriding native DOM method above is only my day-dream. I don't know what is correct syntax :'( Anybody can help?

Here is a reference to ADD custom method to native DOM element:
http://www.meekostuff.net/blog/Overriding-DOM-Methods/

Comment: Here is the reason I said it's not good for human to read: Some elements use `src` attribute and some use `href`. Some others use other attribute name. To reduce the risk of maintaining the code(as you can see:anyth got double), I hope I can centralize them into few lines.

Comment: This is something that's probably possible with [Polymer.](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/)

Comment: @Pointy The hateful-M$-VS-like logo stop me to look further lol